# Get count of series/groups based on 14 days of interval

Tags: postgresql

I have a table containing range table like this.

```
+---------+---------+
| user_id | view_dt |
+---------+---------+
| A       |     1/1 |
+---------+---------+
| A       |    1/10 |
+---------+---------+
| A       |    1/14 |
+---------+---------+
| A       |    1/22 |
+---------+---------+
| A       |    1/23 |
+---------+---------+
| A       |    1/30 |
+---------+---------+
```

I want this data to be grouped based on a 14 day interval. That is, the groups would be:

GROUP 1: 1/1, 1/10, 1/14

GROUP 2： 1/22, 1/23, 1/30

Basically I want to count the orders by interval. So Output should be:

```
user_id A, count of groups = 2
```

Note that I the 1/30 date should belong to GROUP 2 since 1/30 should be compared to the first date of GROUP 2 (1/22) instead of

I think it can be achieved by creating a recursive query because my grouping condition is 14 days from the first date of the group. Just curious if there's an alternative solution to the recursive CTE method?

Thanks!

Comment: It is not quiteas easy as one might think. What is a 14 days interval? When to start? Each month, each year? Start at 1970-01-01? Start at 0? Are you aware, that then at month changes usually there's an overlap (parts of month 1 and month 2)= Or do you just want to split a month into two parts? Is the split at half? At 14? At 15? And last but not least: Your "range" column should be either normalized (split month and day) or better: use a date type instead.

Comment: @S-Man Hi there! so I'd like the 14-d window to start on the first view_dt for each user as there's multiple users in the database too. In this case that'd be 1/1/ 2022. The view_dt could be any days in 2022.